# Java 8 Function<String, Void> vs Consumer<String>

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, runnable, callable

I can't for the life of me find an explanation of the following:

```
public static void takesAFunction(Function<String, Void> func) {
    func.apply("Hi I'm running a function");
}

public static void takesAConsumer(Consumer<String> func) {
    func.accept("Hi I'm running a consumer");
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    takesAFunction((String str) -> { System.out.println(str); });
    takesAConsumer((String str) -> { System.out.println(str); });
}
```

I'm using JDK 1.8.0_66 and the line

```
takesAFunction((String str) -> { System.out.println(str); });
```

is marked as an error saying that

```
The method takesAFunction(Function<String,Void>) in the type MyClass 
is not applicable for the arguments ((String str) -> {})
```

I can't understand how is

```
Function<String, Void>
```

different from

```
Consumer<String>
```

when both return nothing and both take in a single String parameter.

Can someone pls shed some light on this cos it's killing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You aren't returning a `Void` value.

Comment: Similarly, there is a difference between `Runnable` and `Callable<Void>` as `Void` is a reference to a class which can only be `null` (Unless you use reflection to create one)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `Function<String, Void>` should have the following signature:

```
Void m(String s);
```

not to be confused with `void m(String s);`!

So you need to return a `Void` value - and the only one available is `null`:

```
takesAFunction((String str) -> {
  System.out.println(str);
  return null;
});
```

compiles as expected.

Comment: Oh got it - thanks a ton!